# LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE for "NT SERVICE\ServiceName

Tags: windows, winapi

`LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE` can be used to create logon for built-in service accounts *Network Service*, *Local Service*, *SYSTEM*:

```
LogOnUser("SYSTEM", "NT AUTHORITY", nullptr, LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, &token);
```

Is it possible to create a logon for "NT SERVICE\ServiceName"? When I try this:

```
LogOnUser("SomeService", "NT SERVICE", nullptr, LOGON32_LOGON_SERVICE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, &token);
```

I get:

"*The user name or password is incorrect*".

Comment: You mean LogonUser, I assume, not LogOnUser?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to be able to generate a token for SYSTEM like that.  At least, it doesn't seem to be documented.  It may be a bug, or a rogue feature.

Comment: If you changed the 5th parameter to `LOGON32_PROVIDER_VIRTUAL` the function parameters would be correct, but the logon attempt will be denied with ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED. @HarryJohnston At least in newer msdn docs logging on the "LocalService" account is documented.

Comment: @klaustriendl, [I don't see it?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw)  Can you point to whatever documentation you've found?  (Also, Googling `LOGON32_PROVIDER_VIRTUAL` finds some third-party references but nothing from Microsoft that I can see.)

Comment: It's in the [examples section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonuserw#examples). `LOGON32_PROVIDER_VIRTUAL` is undocumented but exists in the SDK, and it matches perfectly with "NT SERVICE\ServiceName" being a virtual service account - plus the Service Control Manager is using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume no here. I can't see any docs anywhere to support logging in with Virtual Accounts, only using them in the setup for a service (CreateService) and assigning to IIS App Pool.

One doc seems a bit out of place since this article refers to a virtual account created on install but I think they really mean assigned to the service - since virtual accounts *cannot* be created. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2832204

"When WID is installed, the NT SERVICE\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID local virtual account is created"

Since no other docs anywhere mention this - I have to concur this isn't possible.

You are running a special type of account here that has a single purpose.

Comment: I didn't know you could use virtual accounts with IIS.  I wonder how IIS gains access to the accounts?