# Create process as different local system user

Tags: windows, visual-c++, msdn

I can create new process from my application with different user account. In this case I should use some function like `CreateProcessWithLogonW`. I would like not to set user in system, but get super rights. I have seen that some services are running in the name of `Local system account`. Can I create some process that runs from `Local System account`

Comment: You mean like, you know, a service?

Comment: Vico, the supported method is to install a temporary service and either run your code directly in the service (preferable) or to steal its token to use when launching your process.  However, [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34860085/886887) claims to get a system token by calling LogonUser.  YMMV.